How to shut YOLOv8 prediction/detection window via Python?
When you try to close the window manually, opened through Python (I am using Visual Studio), the window closes for a split second before reopening. CLI allows the window to be closed manually but I would like to avoid using that so I can more extensively use YOLO later.
Please give me some leniency as I am fairly new to python and I know this code will be shoddy.
Initially, I tried to use a while loop with a counter before using cv2 to close everything:
from ultralytics import YOLO 
import cv2 

# run yolo predict window
model = YOLO("yolov8m.pt")
results = model.predict(source="0", show = True)

running  = True

while running: 
    k = k + 1
    print(k)
    # wait for enough time to have passed for the app to open
    if k == 30000:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()



I eventually figured out that this wouldn't work as it would sequentially run the predict window and wouldn't stop running it, meaning it wouldn't close until it was closed (recursive much...)
So I've been trying to use the multiprocess module, which eventually ended me up here:
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.process

running = True 

def camera():
        model = YOLO("yolov8m.pt")
        results = model.predict(source="0", show=True)

def counter():
        k = 1
        while running:
            k = k + 1
            print(k)
            if k == 40000:
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    counterProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=counter)
    cameraProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=camera)

    counterProcess.start()
    cameraProcess.start()

    counterProcess.join()
    cameraProcess.join()



It successfully runs both programs, as it prints numbers until 40,000, but cv2.destroyAllWindows() doesn't close the camera window. Why?
Is there a different close function to use or should this be working?
